# Parse JS - Query not return correct results

Tags: javascript, parsing, backbone.js

So I have a simple code into a backbone-style web app

```
    var $content = $('section').first(),
            document = new Parse.Query('Document'),
            pId = "fsSGsG323";   // my document id into database


    document.equalTo('personPointer', {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Person",
        objectId: pId
    }).descending('createdAt').find().then(function(documents) {
       alert(documents.length + ' documents found');
        for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            var $li = $("<li class='reportDocumentsItem'></li>");

            var aux = new ProductListItem({
                el: $li,
                model: documents[i]
            });
            $content.append(aux.$el);
        }
    }, genFail);
```

i have 10 entries into the DB that have as a "personPointer" the right "pId",
but sometimes, randomly, while i'm using the web app,
the alert shows me that there are 0 or less results then i actually have...
so i refresh the page, and everything works well

where is my mistake???what am i missing??